# Gulp browsersync pipe not working

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm trying to get browsersync (with stream) working, but it doesn't seem to work in pipe context. The sass compiles correctly, then nothing happens. My code is as follows:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('../css/source/*.scss')
    .on('error', function (err) {

         notify.onError({
           title:    "Gulp",
           subtitle: "Failure!",
           message:  "<%= error.message %>",
           sound:    "Beep"
       })(err);
       this.emit('end');
    })

    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(concat('build.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../css/build/dev'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
    .pipe(csso())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../css/build/min'));
});


gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function(){

    gulp.watch('../css/source/*.scss', ['sass']);

});
```

In my terminal it does seem to register it though:

```
[BS] 1 file changed (build.css)
[BS] File changed: ../css/build/dev/build.css
```

The only way I can get a reload to happen is to add it to the watch task:

```
gulp.watch("../css/build/dev/*.css",  browserSync.reload);
```

... but with this method I can't seem to enable the stream, as it doesn't accept a function. I have also tried browserSync.stream() as per the current docs to no avail.

Here is the browsersync task if it helps:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: 'local.test.com',
        host: '10.0.1.40'
    });
});
```

Please help!

Comment: Hi Chris, is your aim just to use browser-sync to reload browser and inject changes to CSS files?

Comment: Yes, at the moment I just want to inject styles instead of reloading the browser.

Comment: I've done this a lot with Stylus for simple projects not SASS, I can propose a solution but it might be different to your setup slightly, it uses nodemon and browser-sync to inject changes to css and reloads js/html if it detects changes in that. The difference is mostly in how i structured the code and my css pre-processor.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the pipe to `browserSync` in task `sass`, and add a `files` key to `browserSync.init()`:

```
browserSync.init({
  ...
  files: ['../css/**/*.css'],
  ...
});
```

With the above setup you need neither `gulp.watch()` (that's for starting tasks based on file changes) nor a gulp task that depends on `browserSync`. Simply run `gulp browser-sync`.

Note that this watches the CSS directly to avoid a race condition between the `scss` changes and `browserSync`.